# Can I use http://schema.org/Article for an article preview?

Tags: schema.org

I have a list of short previews for articles, can I use it like this: Is this the right way to use this schema type or is it just for the whole article?

```
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <h2 itemprop="headline" > <a href="the_permalink()"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <label>Author : <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" ><span itemprop="name"><?php echo is_page($object_id) ? 'Yaez Verlag GmbH' : get_the_author(); ?></span></span></label>
                        <label>Date : <?php echo get_the_date( 'c', $object_id ); ?> </label>
... more code and a very shortend version of the content
</div>
```

Comment: Good question...have you tried it to find out?

Comment: Thanks that answered my question.